# How to adapt Noise Reduction Audacity C++ code to android

Tags: android, c++, noise-reduction

I am in the process to add a noise reduction mechanism to my android app that saves wildlife sounds.

I then thought about directly adding C++ Audacity Noise reduction algorithm to my java code, and ONLY this part of Audacity. The file is publicly available here: [NoiseRemoval.cpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/audacity/audacity/master/src/effects/NoiseRemoval.cpp). To my ear, the algorithm seems quite good with acceptable drawbacks.

Of course I could port it to java, but it has many recursive `includes`, and it will be (considerably?) slower. Not worth it.

Does this makes sense? Would it be too hard to adapt the code?

Comment: Where are you going to get  your FFT library from?  This the main dependency here.

Comment: That is fine, only one thing: I thought about using JTransforms, that I already made it work. The problem is the other dozens of files...

Comment: Yes, that sounds promising.  I wonder how fast it is? (Hint: use a power of two for your window size).  What you might do is build Audacity from source (with optimisation disabled) and step through it with a debugger.  I generally find that the quickest way to learn.  My weapon of choice is Visual Studio - the debugger is superb (other debuggers are available).

Comment: It seems JT is fast, although I don't really need speed. I don't need real time processing. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing would be to make the c code work in Visual Studio or cLion if you haven't done it already. you can input some sample input files, and apply the noise cancelation function to that file iteratively, chunk by chunk to simulate real-time output. Now, if the output is satisfactory you can move on to the next part.

you can use JNI(Java Native Interface), which acts as an interface to call native library functions from java. you can just read about JNI which won't take much time. then you can bundle your c code after exposing only the necessary processing functions that you will need to call from java. Then connect your c noise cancelation library to your java project using JNI and peacefully call c functions from java without rewriting all code from c to java and make your necessary adjustments.
Moreover, you can use webRTC Noise Cancelation / Auto Gain Control modules which can work realtime if it is not working on realtime.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Given that webRTC is for communication, I would expect its noise cancelation to be speech-oriented, no? I already tried using VOICE as the capture device instead of MIC, and the result is not satisfactory.

Comment: There are many types of noises. If you wanna remove certain set of noises which is specific to you may be you have design your own ML based noise cancelation first which can be trained by taking input of noise sounds. Then you can just train that by inputing "hiss" sound or "wind" or natural sounds that you wanna remove from captured mixed audio. There can be this types of project already.

Comment: That could be a great idea. I will think how to implement that. Thanks!

Comment: welcome..! would love to hear if you end up being successful using this technique as I am working in this noise cancelation area too but for a different use case..

Comment: Sure, I will report back.